# Highcharter R shiny line chart display correctly on local machine but when publish to shinyapps.io server it distorts

Tags: r, shiny, highcharts, shinyapps

I have built a line chart using the highcharter library. When I run the app on my machine it displays the line chart as intended as follows:
[image]

However when I publish the app on shinyapps.io server the line chart is distorted as follows:
[image]

How can I make the line chart display the same on the shinyapps.io server

Here is the piece of script that generates the line chart

```
output$displaylinechart <- renderHighchart({
                   highchart(width = 1043) %>%
                     hc_add_series(data = df_epc(), hcaes(x = Date, y = Value),type = "spline", lineWidth = 1, shadow = list(color = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)', blur = 7,color = "#0291da"), showInLegend = FALSE) %>%
                     hc_tooltip(shared = TRUE, crosshairs = TRUE, formatter = JS("function() {
    var tp = [];
    var tp1 = [];
    this.points.forEach(function(point) {
      var oT = new Date(point.x);
      var val = parseFloat(point.y);
      tp.push(oT.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: 'short'}));
      tp1.push(val.toFixed(1));
    });
    return '<b>Time: </b>' + tp.join('<br>') + '<br><b>Index Value: </b>' + tp1.join('<br>');
  }")) %>%
                     hc_xAxis(type = 'datetime', title = list(text = 'Time', style= list(
                       fontFamily= 'Arial',
                       fontWeight= 'bold'
                     )), labels = list(format = '{value:%Y}'), showZeroLine= TRUE, lineColor = "black") %>%
                     hc_yAxis(title = list(text = 'Policy Certainty Index',style= list(
                       fontFamily= 'Arial',
                       fontWeight= 'bold'
                     )), opposite = FALSE,
                              minorGridLineWidth= 0,
                              gridLineWidth= 0,lineWidth = 1, lineColor = "black")
                 })
```

Comment: Can you share your data? Looks to me like the data either isn't sorted properly or it isn't in datetime format. Are you sure everything is identical b/w running locally vs on shinyapps.io? as in same package versions etc?

Comment: Hello Jamie. Here is the data attached. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qv-te9XygQZDM9xz8V1U37-pbmGreSKt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The issue is with the date format. It seems that the date format is working on my local machine but somehow not working on the server. I don't know which format the server use for date.

Comment: use `sessionInfo()` locally and when you publish to see what the differences are between the two environments.

Comment: It's obvious that the shinyapps version fails to parse the month and day, so all values from the same year are placed in the same position. Looking at [highchart's date format](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.dateFormat) I'd advise to try using slashes as separators instead of dashes, if possible,  in the date strings, or setting a javascript [parseDate](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.parseDate) function. The difference between the two results is possibly due to a difference in the version of highcharter and/or the underlying highcharts library.

Comment: Hello @kikon thanks for replying. The highchart package is the same version on the server and my machine. How do I parse the data format with slashes in R shiny highchart. It does not recognize slash in the as.Date function.

Comment: I have tried echarts4r and also plotly linechart. Still with those two I got the same issue. I think its about the date format that is not recognized properly on the server.

Comment: I was wrong, I tested it on shinnyapps;  you don't have to change the string date format, it works well with the raw data, applying highcharter's `datetime_to_timestamp`, but even without it, you don't lose the month and day, see https://kikon.shinyapps.io/date_test/. I think the problem is in your `df_epc()` function, it's there where the month and day of the date string get cut out - please add the code on how you get and process the actual data.

Comment: Yeah you are right. The df_epc() is querying my database table. The csv I shared is the output from the df_epc() dataframe. It's very strange when I query the data from the database and query it from the csv the data type for the column date are the same that is char but when using the dataframe to convert to date both give me different output of the chart. I don't know why. I did a workaround which I will have to change later. What I did is query the data from the database then write it to a csv then I queried the csv and use the data in the chart which works strangely.